# How to Append to a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

I need to write a simple python script for a table and I need to append to a CSV file

I am creating a table that will read data from a CSV file. How do I append a new line to the CSV file so that my table will have more rows.

Comment: How does a table read from a CSV file?